# Persistent cart = off, adding 1 product and login results in 12 products in cart

Tags: checkout, cart, session

we are having some issues with sessions it seems. Messages from customers like 'my cart is suddenly empty after login (account)', or 'my cart suddenly has many items after login'. When testing I see something similar.

Situation now

- Persistent cart = off
- I visit site => cart has 0 items
- I add 1 product
- Go to checkout and login as regular customer
- login results in 12 products in cart (and I am directed to cart instead of next step in checkout)

I would expect

- login success, goes to next step in checkout
- cart items are as before login (just the 1 product)

How can I set up the behavior that I am expecting. Many thanks!

Comment: Where there products in the cart of the account you used to login? After login the old cart and the new cart are merged.

Comment: hmmm Yes I imagine so. And I understand that this is probably the reason. But the behavior is just annoying. Customers do not understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behavior for Magento as is.

We solved this by installing this extension: https://github.com/jacquesbh/jbh_cartmerge

It has option to turn on/off merging of carts, also to enforce mergen when the cart is empty

Should be default setting in Magento ...

Comment: I disagree with that, you want returning customers to have the ease to pick-up where they left. This is provided by Magento by default and will cause more sales in one checkout for returning customers. That's why this functionality exists in the first place. I understand if you really don't like it, there is always a developer who provides a solution for you in a module form

Comment: That's you right. What do you disagree with? Ps. it is not always about more sales.

Comment: I could use service in the same sentence. I agree with you for this particular shop. On big b2b websites, customers are always more than happy to pickup where they left. If you ask me, it would even better that the customer would have a choice. Login, Notice: "Do you want to pick-up where you left?" and "see what was in your cart the last time" You would have best of both worlds.

Comment: Customers are often "not logged in" - also suddenly adding the items in checkout step (without warning) is killing ... people claim the site is broken ... so in the end we are just helping our customers. Now with the extension we have no more complaints.